# Why does dput have more precision than the original?

Tags: r

I am using `R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)`. I noticed something strange with the precision of rational numbers when using `dput`. For example:

```
1/3
# [1] 0.3333333
dput(1/3)
# 0.333333333333333
```

Why does `dput` produce an object with many more decimal places that is not identical to the original?

Comment: It only _displays_ more precision.  Try `options(digits = 16)`  the type in `1/3`

Comment: hmm. if it only displays more precision why is: `identical(1/3, 0.333333333333333)` false on my system?

Comment: That's because `dput()` also doesn't display all the digits by default. `identical(1/3, 0.33333333333333331483)` will return TRUE. Floating point numbers are tricky. Learn more at [why are these numbers not equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal)

Comment: Thanks... this should probably be a separate question, but how do you get `dput` to display the output with sufficient precision so that `identical` returns true?

Comment: Ok, i've worked out that if I print with digits = 22 I get `identical(1/3, 0.33333333333333331)` to be `TRUE`. Which is not the decimal you have (although that one also returns true on my system).

Comment: `identical` doesn't seem like the right tool for comparing floating point numbers. I think `all.equal` is what you want -  `all.equal(1/3, 0.333333333333333)` == `TRUE` for example.

Comment: @Alex Well, note that `identical(0.33333333333333331483, 0.33333333333333331)` is TRUE. R can only keep track of so many decimals. I think my number may have lied. I had used `sprintf("%.20f",1/3)` to generate it. What are you actually doing that you need this equality? Doing quality testing with floating point numbers isn't very straightforward.

Comment: My usual strategy for unit testing is to `dput` the object I know to be correct and use it for testing. Today I am generating unit tests involving matrices. But obviously the precision affects the output of `identical` and I couldn't work out why `dput` was not working the way I have been using it. So, thank you.